# App submission and approval on Hackintosh (2016)

Tags: ios-appstore, mac-appstore, development

We just recently developed an iOS app on a iMac. The process to get the approval tooks us 15 days.

Our Mac got damaged and won't turn on. We need to keep developing while the Mac is on repair. **Will there be any trouble for the submission and approval of our app if we develop it on a Hackintosh?**

I know that there are a lot of similar questions but those relate of 2011. Now I think Apple has got more strict in the reviews of the apps, so I would like to know please how are they managing this in the recent days. Thanks

Comment: You would risk your reputation with Apple by breaking the software license for OS X rather than get a loaner Mac to run builds for the week or two it might take? Also - how would you know the compiler would work correctly and then you'd have a problematic build on the app store live in customer's hands?

Comment: Fear should not give advises